# SQL Server Partitioned tables and full text indexing

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, partitioning

Using SQL Server 2016+

I have a products table that requires partioning.  It currently has a primary Identity key which is used as part of a full text index search.  We need to partition the table a a field that is not the primary key ( a division id ) to aid with importing data and seperating data out onto multiple drives.  Example below is a simple case without the partitions all on Primary but enough to demonstrate.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Products
BEGIN TRY DROP PARTITION SCHEME division_id_scheme      END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH
BEGIN TRY DROP PARTITION FUNCTION division_id_function  END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH
BEGIN TRY DROP FULLTEXT CATALOG ProductNames            END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION division_id_function ( INT )  AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES ( 1, 2, 3 )
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME division_id_scheme AS PARTITION division_id_function ALL TO ( [PRIMARY] )

CREATE TABLE dbo.Products ( ID           INT           IDENTITY(1, 1)
,                           Catalogueref NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
,                           ProductName  NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
,                           DivisionID   INT           NOT NULL
,                           CONSTRAINT pk_Products PRIMARY KEY ( DivisionID, ID )) ON division_id_scheme (DivisionID);

INSERT INTO dbo.Products ( Catalogueref, ProductName, DivisionID )
VALUES ( N'ABC123', N'Product Apple', 1 )
,      ( N'ABC124', N'Product Ball', 1 )
,      ( N'ABC125', N'Product Cat', 2 )
,      ( N'ABC126', N'Product Dog', 2 )
,      ( N'ABC127', N'Product Egg', 3 )
,      ( N'ABC128', N'Product Fox', 3 )
,      ( N'ABC129', N'Product Grape', 3 )

SELECT * FROM  dbo.Products
```

This creates and partions the table exactly as expected.  The issue comes when we try to create the full text index.  The full text index requires a unique key that is defined against a single column.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ProductNames

--This Fails because pk_Products is not a single column unique index
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Products (ProductName) KEY INDEX pk_Products ON ProductNames

Msg 7653, Level 16, State 2, Line 29
'pk_Products' is not a valid index to enforce a full-text search key. A full-text search key must be a unique, non-nullable, single-column index which is not offline, is not defined on a non-deterministic or imprecise nonpersisted computed column, does not have a filter, and has maximum size of 900 bytes. Choose another index for the full-text key.
```

However we cannot create a unique key against a single column as we require two columns in the primary key for partitioning.

```
-- This fails because unique index must be a subset of the index (which is multi-column)
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS ui_CatRef ON dbo.Products
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ui_CatRef ON dbo.Products (Catalogueref)
```

Both DivisionID and ID are required in the primary key as Division ID is not unique, but is how we are partitioning data.  We have already tried several options including:

- Adding a computed column based on the ID
- Adding a normal column and manually populating the value to replicate the ID

Neither of which work as a unique index must include the partitioned fields.

Any suggestions on how we can partition by the division, but still maintain a primary key for full text searching would be greatfully received.

Comment: you can create unique index on primary filegroup me thinks? `CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ui_CatRef ON dbo.Products (id) on [primary]

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Products (ProductName) KEY INDEX ui_CatRef ON ProductNames`

Comment: @siggemannen 100% correct,  Out of habbit I don't list the filegroup.  Hence the issue.  If you'd like to add this as an answer I'll accept it so you get the credit.  Many thanks.

Comment: added, but with a little caveat emptor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create unique index on primary filegroup to avoid this issue:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ui_CatRef ON dbo.Products (id) on [primary]
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Products (ProductName) KEY INDEX ui_CatRef ON ProductNames
```

I gotta say though that this solution feels a bit hacky to me, so please make sure it doesn't lead to any unintended consequences later

Comment: Thanks.  We are using table partitions in a bit of an odd way, but this solved the problem perfectly for me.  Credit where its due.